# using Correlation variable as a boundary in another extractor in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

How to use a newly created variable (from JSON Extractor) as a boundary to the new extracor. Is it possible to use variable name as left boundary in another extractor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the JMeter Variable **already** has the value by the time you want to use it in the Boundary Extractor you should be good to go and use it as left/right boundary:

Demo (assumes [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) and [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/))

[image]